# Why can't the compiler use the std::string conversion function of the class when perform operator<<?

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, stdstring

Consider the following `struct` with a user-defined conversion function that can convert itself to `const char*`;

```
struct S {
  operator const char*() { return "hello"; }
};
```

This work with `<iostream>`, we can print the `struct S` with no error message:

```
std::cout << S{} << '\n';
```

But if I change the return type to `std::string`:

```
struct S {
  operator std::string() { return "hello"; }
};
```

I got this compiler error message:

```
<source>:11:13: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'S')
11 |   std::cout << S{} << '\n';
   |   ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~
   |        |       |
   |        |       S
   |        std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
    <source>:11:18: note:   'S' is not derived from 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>'
11 |   std::cout << S{} << '\n';
   |                  ^
```

Why can't the compiler use the `std::string` conversion? Is there a difference between the conversion function of the built-in and class type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`operator<<` for `std::basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is a template taking 3 template parameters:

> ```
> template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
> std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
>     operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
>                const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
> ```

And implicit conversion won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions):

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

Then given `std::cout << S{};`, the template parameter `CharT`, `Traits` and `Allocator` can't be deduced on the 2nd function argument.

On the other hand, [`operator<<` for `const char*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) doesn't have such issue; given `std::cout << S{};`, the template parameter `CharT` and `Traits` would be deduced only from the 1st function argument. After deduction, the implicit conversion from `S` to `const char*` will be performed and the calling works well.